# Find and Replace keeps crashing

Tags: vba, excel, replace, find

I am using a Find and Replace, simple VBA code as below:

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()
'Update 20140722
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, 
InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However, the dataset is over 685,000 values large and this keeps crashing my excel document. I've tried putting in error catches and other methods to find and replace.

Both columns are in sheet2. Column to be replaced is column 10, column and replacement are in columns 17 and 18.

The data looks like this

**Time With Bank**  **Time With Bank** **Transformed Score**

```
999               999                 5
5                 1                   4
27                2                   4
3                 3                   2
...               ...                 ...
999               207                 1.3
```

Looking To replace all of the first column which has 686950 entries with the transformed score (column 3) of each of column 2, which has the time with bank for 80 different monthly entries.

Comment: would a simple `VLOOKUP` suffice instead?

Comment: The problem is that I have a column with 686,950 entries that need to be replaced. The number of entries for time with bank is 80 and the transformed score accompanying it also has 80 values.

Comment: Ok, if you insist on using VBA then one comment it would make it to consider looping through the InputRng rather than the ReplaceRng. At the moment you are doing 686950 * 80 operations. If you looped through InputRng, then compared the cell with each cell in the ReplaceRng and exited the inner loop once you replaced the value you'd probably halve the time it takes (ie you find the number on average after 40 cells). If you used a smarter search (eg binary search) you could get it down to 6 * 686950 operations.

Comment: Tbh, i'm happy to use any programme like R, Stata, MATLAB. Just I can't find a way to replace the column.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have a calculation cycle based on the replacement of a value in hte worksheet. This could be due to a precedent formula that references one or more cells in the inputRng or a volatile formula (e.g. INDIRECT, ADDRESS, TODAY, NOW, etc) in any open workbook. You might also have event dependent code within the worksheet's code sheet (e.g. Worksheet_Change, etc) or the workbook's code page (e.g. Workbook_SheetChange, etc).

Turn off calculation and disable events at the same time you turn off screen updating.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

'... all of the processing code

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Your sub procedure may also benefit from working 'in-memory' and replacing the values *en masse* once all replacements have been performed. I received a ~30% increase in efficiency on a i5 Surface Pro using the following method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub multiFindNReplace2()
    Dim rng As Variant, xTitleId As String, r As Long
    Dim dataRng As Variant, mtch As Variant, inputRng As Range, replaceRng As Range

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set inputRng = Application.InputBox(PROMPT:="Original Range:", Title:=xTitleId, Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    rng = Application.InputBox(PROMPT:="Replacement Range:", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="$M$2:$N$81", Type:=8).Value2
    dataRng = inputRng.Value2


    Debug.Print Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For r = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
        mtch = Application.Match(rng(r, 1), dataRng, 0)
        Do While Not IsError(mtch)
            dataRng(mtch, 1) = rng(r, 2)
            mtch = Application.Match(rng(r, 1), dataRng, 0)
        Loop
    Next r

    inputRng.Resize(UBound(dataRng, 1), UBound(dataRng, 2)) = dataRng

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow morning, appreciate it

Comment: Still crashes my Excel, i just think my university Computers can't handle it

Comment: Thanks for your code, I have settled on running 50k entries at a time, I'll try find a way to do a for loop for 50k at a time